# Task Push Queue executes to frequently

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Queue setup:

```
queue:
- name: my-queue
  rate: 30/h
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  bucket_size: 1
```

Reading this I would say that this queue will process 1 task every 2 minutes. This isn't the case, when I add 40 tasks to the queue they all get processed within a couple seconds.

The goal is to process 1 task every 2 minutes.

Tested on the Development Server (Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The local development server does not respect the `rate` or `bucket_size` fields.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/using-the-development-server)

I think the closest you can get is having max 1 task executed every minute.

```
queue:
- name: my-queue
  rate: 1/m
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  bucket_size: 1
```

Comment: It is within the rate limit. But the bucket_size is only 1. Shouldn't that limit the process frequency?  Updated question to reflect 1 every 2 minutes as its a better test case.

Comment: @PimReijersen Updated my answer, I had not noticed that you were testing this on the local development server.